# BIOS-Access Problems on Lenovo, Xubuntu installed over (a deleted) Windows 8

Tags: boot, wireless, xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu on my friend's system awhile back, and it was working perfectly when I gave it to him -- it booted up, connected to the Internet, ran YouTube videos, all that jazz -- but he recently brought it back and it has a few major problems that baffle me. I was hoping maybe someone more experienced could help me figure this out.

First of all, nm-connection-editor is broken. I have no idea how or why. When I try to add a wifi connection, many of the necessary fields are deactivated -- e.g., I cannot enter an SSID for a new connection, so wireless connection is hopeless.

Second, when I try to plug in via wire, I still don't get an Internet connection. When I open a browser, I get ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED. When I try to use "ifup wlan0", wlan0 is not found. When I try "ifconfig up", error fetching interface information: device not found.

I have no clue how the wifi became nonfunctional, so I figured I might just try reinstalling XFCE -- BUT I can't even do THAT, because -- problem number three -- my BIOS appears to be totally inaccessible. I have tried both restarting and shutting down, and neither process gives me any opportunity to boot to the BIOS, even if I spam all the F-keys and Delete and Escape before the GRUB menu ever appears. There is no Lenovo splash screen of any kind during which it would ordinarily make sense to interject with F2 or F12 or Delete or whatever. Therefore, I can't even boot from USB.

Does anyone have any bright ideas for resolving this? I am open to anything -- even reinstalling the whole damn computer -- if I can just get it to work.
I have flash drives through which I can get offline installers onto the Lenovo, if that helps. And it boots up into Xubuntu just fine -- other than the whole nothing-important-actually-works part.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

As requested, here is the output of lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net:

02:00.0 Network Controller (0280): Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b4] (rev 93)

Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160

Kernel Driver in use: iwlwifi

...

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)

Subsystem: Lenovo Device (17aa:3818]

Kernel driver in use: r8169

Hope this helps someone :(

UPDATE: Solved -- thanks a lot to Jeremy31 for the tip. To anyone who is curious for details, I pressed something that he called the "Novo" button, which is apparently a tiny pinhole button under a looping arrow somewhere on the side of your laptop -- it opened the boot menu, so I reordered boot process, but that didn't work because UEFI skipped my USB anyway and booted straight to GRUB -- so then I changed from UEFI to Legacy boot mode, confirmed the proper order, and it booted effortlessly into my installer USB as if there was never any problem.

Comment: My Lenovo has a 'Novo' button that is used to power up to access the BIOS, check the owners manual.  When I installed Ubuntu in EFI mode, it gave me a 'System Settings' option in GRUB that gave me BIOS settings access.  Please add the results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to the question

Comment: Just posted the request details.

I cannot find a "Novo" button -- unless it's this tiny pinhole button with a looping arrow drawn on it -- and I don't have an owner's manual because it's my friend's computer... I tried checking online but didn't see much... I'm about to look again but if I don't edit this before you reply, there's probably a good chance that I would benefit from a description of this mysterious Novo button...

Thanks!

Comment: The looping arrow button is likely it.  Power down the computer and then push the button.  It must not be disabled in BIOS, but check `rfkill list all` for anything being blocked

Comment: Thanks so much, my friend -- we have achieved great victory. Fedora seems to be reinstalling. You're my hero. :) [to anyone who is curious for details, I pressed that button, it opened the boot menu, I reordered boot process, that didn't work because UEFI skipped my USB anyway and booted straight to GRUB, so then I changed from UEFI to Legacy boot mode, confirmed the proper order, and it booted into my installer USB].

Comment: PS, is there a way to mark this "Solved" or anything like that on this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Novo button on Lenovo's can usually give access to the BIOS settings and the button looks like [image]

Shutdown the computer and use the button to start the computer and you should see a menu like

[image]

And from there you can get into the BIOS settings

Comment: Ah, I see, you have to answer all officially and such. Nice update. Answer verified as useful. :)